# Ошибка запуска webpack и webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server

Создаю клиентское приложение на `React` и `Redux`. Использую `Webpack`. При начальных настройках `webpack-config.js` сервер запускается. Вот начальные настройки:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
};
```

Потом когда поменял конфигурационный файл и он стал таким, то сервер начал не запускаться:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.jsx'
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'react-hot!babel'
            }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Это ошибка в консоли при запуске `webpack-dev-server`:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>   -configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

А это иерархия приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот измененный вариант `webpack.config.js`. И сейчас уже `devserver` работает нормально, с различными `loader`-ами.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/build/',
    publicPath: "build/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader",
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.gif$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif"
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg"
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png"
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=26000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: "react-hot!babel-loader",
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```